# jQuery Bootgrid Conditional Icon in Header Cell

Tags: jquery-bootgrid

I'd like to add an icon to the header cell if a condition is met.
I know that in the documentation it mentions that [dynamic placholders](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/documentation#dynamic) are a thing, but it doesn't elaborate on how to add your own.

---

**What I've tried:**

Defining my own Template:

```
templates: {
    headerCell: '<th data-column-id="{{ctx.column.id}}">{{ctx.column.text}}{{ctx.column.myCustomIcon}}</th>',
}
```

then in the formatters, adding the custom field.

```
formatters: {
  myCustomField: function(column, row){

    column.myCustomIcon = "";

    if (item[column.id] == 0) {
      return "";
    }

    column.myCustomIcon = '<i class="fa fa-shield"></i>';
  }
}
```

Doesn't work, some guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do this without using template, plus creating a new method in their prototype.

Just add this method in their library (jquery.bootgrid.js):

```
Grid.prototype.recreateTableHeader = function () {
    renderTableHeader.call(this);
    return this;
};
```

> This must be placed after they define `var Grid = function(element, options)` around line 974.

Then, you can call this method after the grid is loaded:

```
var columnNameChanged = false;

var grid = $('#my-grid').bootgrid(/* your options here */);

grid.on("loaded.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function () {

    if (!columnNameChanged) {

        columnNameChanged = true;
        var columns = grid.bootgrid('getColumnSettings');
        var column = columns[1];
        column.text = '<i class="fa fa-shield"></i> ' + column.text;

        grid.bootgrid('recreateTableHeader');
    }

});
```

Take note I'm changing the column's **text** property, concatenating the icon with the current `column.text` (which holds the text you put in your HTML). You can change this inside your formatter or inside this `loaded` event like my sample, but since your formatter is called once for each row and I'm appending the `column.text` after the icon markup, you'd end up having a column text like `<i class="fa fa-shield"></i><i class="fa fa-shield"></i><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> Column Name`.